# What is the identity of this fruit/tree found near Berkeley, California, USA?

Tags: species-identification, fruit, trees

Please help identify this fruit/tree found near Berkeley, California.

The tree had no leaves. The fruit looked like a pear from far. It has no flesh. When the outer skin is peeled, the seed looks like a large avocado seed. Very little smell from the fruit/seed not a bad smell and not an appetizing smell as well.

Could this be a [Yellow Buckeye](http://www.oplin.org/tree/fact%20pages/buckeye_yellow/buckeye_yellow.ht)?

[image: Tree With Fruit]

[image: Fruit]

[image: Seed]

[image: Inside the Seed]

Comment: Ask any Ohioan. Looks like a Buckeye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it's in central California, it's almost certainly [California buckeye (*Aesculus californica*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesculus_californica).  The tree is common in the Coast range and Sierra foothills of California.  It has adapted to the Mediterranean climate of the region by growing during the wet winter and spring and then dropping its leaves during the hot, dry summer.  The large seed is toxic if consumed.